# Mathematica flips the sign of a Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, integral-equations, error-tracking

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
Gdd = {{-((E^(2 AA[z]) L^2 g[z, B])/z^2), 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, (
    E^(2 AA[z]) L^2)/(z^2 g[z, B]), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, (
    E^(2 AA[z]) L^2)/z^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, (
    E^(B^2 z^2 + 2 AA[z]) L^2)/z^2, B/bb}, {0, 0, 0, -(B/bb), (
    E^(B^2 z^2 + 2 AA[z]) L^2)/z^2}};
Gddinverse = {{-((E^(-2 AA[z]) z^2)/(L^2 g[z, B])), 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, (
    E^(-2 AA[z]) z^2 g[z, B])/L^2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, (
    E^(-2 AA[z]) z^2)/L^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, (
    bb^2 E^(B^2 z^2 + 2 AA[z]) L^2 z^2)/(
    bb^2 E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z]) L^4 + B^2 z^4), -((B bb z^4)/(
     bb^2 E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z]) L^4 + B^2 z^4))}, {0, 0, 0, (
    B bb z^4)/(bb^2 E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z]) L^4 + B^2 z^4), (
    bb^2 E^(B^2 z^2 + 2 AA[z]) L^2 z^2)/(
    bb^2 E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z]) L^4 + B^2 z^4)}};
AA[z_] = -a z^2;
g[z_, B_] = 
  1 - Integrate[z^3 Exp[-B^2 z^2 - 3 AA[z]], {z, 0, z}]/
   Integrate[z^3 Exp[-B^2 z^2 - 3 AA[z]], {z, 0, zh}];
ff[z_, B_] = -(1/z^2) 2 E^(2 (B^2 z^2 + AA[z])) L^2 Sqrt[
   1 + (B^2 E^(-2 B^2 z^2 - 4 AA[z]) z^4)/(
    bb^2 L^4)] (g[z, B] (-2 + 2 B^2 z^2 + 3 z Derivative[1][AA][z]) + 
     z D[g[z, B], z]);
term[z_, B_] = 
  Sqrt[-Det[Gdd]] Gddinverse[[2, 2]] Gddinverse[[3, 3]] ff[z, B] // 
    PowerExpand // Simplify;
V2[z_] = c1 Log[z] (z^4 (1 + a2 z^2)) + (1 + b2 z^2 + b4 z^4);
eq2[z_] = 
  D[V2[z], {z, 2}] + 
   D[Log[term[z, B] ], z] D[V2[z], 
     z] - \[Omega]^2 ((Gddinverse[[1, 1]]/Gddinverse[[2, 2]])) V2[z];
seriesexpneq12 = Series[eq2[z], {z, 0.0, 1}] // Normal
```

It gives the answer as:

```
-4 b2 + \[Omega]^2
```

But when I use 0.0000000000000001 instead of 0.0, I get the answer:

```
2 b2 + (1. + 1.*10^-32 b2 + 1.*10^-64 b4 - 3.68414*10^-63 c1 - 
   3.68414*10^-95 a2 c1) \[Omega]^2 + (2.*10^-16 b2 + 
    4.*10^-48 b4 + (-1.46365*10^-46 - 
      2.20048*10^-78 a2) c1) (-1.*10^-16 + z) \[Omega]^2
```

Why does Mathematica flip the sign of the leading order term in this case? Which answer should be considered the correct one?

Comment: I suspect this is showing a bug in `Series`, and that the first is the incorrect one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP should report that when expanding near 0.0000000000000001 `General::munfl` will be generated and the numerical result is thus untrustable.

The reason is as follows.

---

The tools are

```
expr=eq2[z];
seriesCompare[expr_,order_:1]:=
    Simplify@N[
        Normal@Series[expr,{z,0,order}]-Chop@Normal@Series[expr,{z,10^-20.,order}]
    ];

symbolExtract[expr_,wrapper_:Identity,opts:OptionsPattern[]] :=
    DeleteDuplicates@Cases[
        expr,
        $$symbol_Symbol?nonsystemQ:>wrapper[$$symbol],
        {0,Infinity},
        FilterRules[{opts},Options[Cases]],
        Heads->False
    ];
nonsystemQ[symbol_Symbol] :=
    Context@symbol=!="System`";
nonsystemQ[_] = False;
```

here `expr` is the expression from OP's code, `seriesCompare` compares the expansion near 0 and 10^-20, and `symbolExtract` extracts symbols in an expressions.

To separate the relevant part in `expr` we take some symbols at some analytic point by trial and error, until `seriesCompare` generates no-vanishing result,

```
expr1//symbolExtract
expr1=expr//ReplaceAll[{b4->0,zh->1,a->1(*B->1*),\[Omega]->1,L->1,bb->1,a2->1,c1->1}]//Simplify;

seriesCompare/@List@@expr1//TableForm
```

[image]

To see why the 5-th term generates warnings,

```
expr1[[5]]//Denominator
```

[image]

so actually there is a `z`-factor not being cancelled, and if we replace the 5-th term by

```
expr2=expr1[[5]]//Factor//Cancel//Simplify

expr1[[5]]//seriesCompare
expr2//seriesCompare//Simplify
```

the results will match,

[image]

To understand this difference, let's take

```
test=Sin[z]/z;
seriesCompare[test,2]
(*0. +1.20893 10^24 z^2*)
```

the coefficient of `z^2` is (with x=10^-20)

```
e2=Series[test,{z,x,2}]//Normal//Coefficient[#,z,2]&
(*-(Cos[x]/x^2) + Sin[x]/x^3 - Sin[x]/(2 x)*)
```

this vanishes at $O(x)$

```
Series[e2,{x,0,2}]
(*-(1/6)+x^2/20+O[x]^3*)
```

but

```
e2/.x->10^-20//N
(*-1.20893 10^24*)
```

due to numerical precision.

Comment: Another point should be stressed that `Series` is actually not Taylor nor Laurent series according to the documentation

> Series can construct standard Taylor series, as well as certain expansions involving negative powers, fractional powers, and logarithms. 

`seriesCompare[Log[z]]
(*46.0517 - 1.\[CenterDot]10^20 z + Log[z]*)`

And there are log-terms in `expr`, although this is irrelevant to `expr` at order `1`.

Comment: What if I take ``b4->1`` instead of ``b4->0`` in the above analysis?

Comment: @codebpr You can try it yourself. The purpose of specifying the parameters is just to simplify the analysis. Intuitively not all choices of parameters can reveal where the problem is located.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough both results seem to be correct or at least plausible.

```
ee = eq2[z] /. \[Omega] -> omega;
seriesexp1 = Normal[Series[ee, {z, 0, 1}]]
seriesexp2 = Normal[Series[ee, {z, 1/100, 1}]];
seriesexp2[[1 ;; 2]]

(* -4 b2 + omega^2

2 b2 + (3 b4)/2500 *)
```

Now a numeric check.

```
In[512]:= N[{seriesexp1, seriesexp2} /. {c1 -> 2, a2 -> 3, bb -> 5/11,
    B -> 7/13, L -> 11/19, zh -> 13/16, b4 -> 17/3, 
   a -> 19/5, \[Omega] -> 1, b2 -> 2}, 20]

(* Out[512]= {-8.0000000000000000000 + omega^2, -7.9987469301487475467 + 
  1.0001999646629277488 omega^2 + (0.24853150921129158616 + 
     0.039987860268843152426 omega^2) (-0.010000000000000000000 + z)} *)
```